# Advantages and disadvantages of Ruby on Rails polymorphic relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

What advantages and disadvantages do you know of Ruby on Rails polymorphic relationships.

Comment: Won't put it as an answer, because I haven't read it, but this seems to be quite a large article on this topic: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159809241/whats-the-deal-with-rails-polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Advantages:

- You can link anything to anything quite easily
- Adaptable relationships help accommodating unforeseen circumstances
- Very easy to implement relationships
- Great for ad-hoc systems

Disadvantages:

- Foreign keys not practical
- Indexes include another dimension of complexity
- Relationships between tables hard to identify when using STI
- Database diagramming tools cannot interpret
- Not always practical for join models
- Strongly discouraged for systems where data integrity must be verified

I'm a big fan of using relationships of this sort for records that are attached to a large number of things as required, for example, a comment or annotation record which may apply to a wide variety of records.

It is not very well suited for situations where the relationship is exercised in a JOIN frequently. That is, the polymorphic association should not be in the middle of a relationship between records, but as something on the perimeter.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it's not well suited to being in the middle of a relationship between records? Foreign keys aren't practical, but integrity is handled at the Rails layer rather than DB, right?

Comment: Using a polymorphic association in the middle means you have a minimum of three components to your join conditions, four if both relationships are polymorphic. This can have a severely detrimental effect on performance as index size can grow considerably with the number of elements in the key involved. Larger indexes become much more expensive to update, so it's advantageous to index only the minimum that's required. As always, take the time to benchmark any proposed database structure with *large* amounts of data representative of your system at scale.