# What is the benefit of Rails polymorphic associations? Provide some DRYed up code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I know how to build it and I know it reduces the number of tables. Let's say we have a Users Table and a Books table and both have Photos.

Our photos table can have a imageable_id and an imageable_type column. But what benefit does this give us?

**One Benefit:**
1. We have 1 fewer columns in this Photo table since we don't have to build a model_id column for every table that has a Photo. This way... we will fewer null values in columns when a photo belongs to one table but not the other... but is this a speed advantage? Organization advantage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799099/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't neglect the DRY benefit. I mean, using a polymorphic association you're are able to link the behavior expected for an imageable component to any model. You will have not only a better concern separation but also a huge amount of code reused.

Comment: Where does the DRY happen?

Comment: It happens when you generalize the Image component and start using it with both, Books and Photos. Because of this strategy, you're granting access to the given models to any image specific behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide some Rails code that might show how this dries it up?

Comment: Take a look on [this scenario](http://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/02/10/rails-polymorphic-models/). Let's say that you want a method called nickname, which is part of the Profile. Without the association, you'd have to define it for each model, for instance.