# What is the benefit of Rails polymorphism over multiple foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

Does it just save your table a column if you have more than 2 `belongs_to` to implement? I don't see any other reason for a resource to just have multiple foreign keys.

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799099/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages and disadvantages of Ruby on Rails polymorphic relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799099/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-relationships)

Comment: The benefit of polymorphism is that it lets you create a single association which points to an arbitrary number of tables. But like metaprograming its widely overused by dev's that have just discovered it.